# How to set individual x-axis when there is multiple variables in cols with facet_grid_sc

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am trying to customize the scales for each x-axis, but I always get the error below:

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Below is script I am trying to create. Customize the x-axis is needed, because its values are crowded.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(facetscales)

country=factor(c(rep("Japan", 3), rep("US",4), rep("Europe", 7),rep("US",3), "Europe", rep("Japan", 3), rep("US",4), rep("Europe", 3), "US", rep("Europe", 3)))
mtcarros <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(country=country)

# How should I create the individual scales for the x-axis
scales_x <- list()

ggplot(mtcarros, aes(mpg, cyl))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid_sc(gear~carb+country, scales = list(x=scales_x))
```

So my questions is: How to create the individual scales for the x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you report is occurring because you have two variables on the right hand side of your faceting formula - this isn't possible, since it implies a 3-D array of facets rather than a 2-D array (`carb` would have to be "coming out of the screen"). It is possible to *nest* facets using other extension packages such as `ggh4x`to allow a third faceting dimension, but this seems tangential to your main question of how to use `facet_grid_sc`

To do this, you need to make a named  `list` of scale objects, with one scale for each named level:

```r
scales_x <- list(Japan = scale_x_continuous(label = ~paste(.x, "km/l")),
                 US = scale_x_continuous(label = ~paste(.x, "mpg")),
                 Europe = scale_x_continuous(label = ~paste(.x, "km/l")))

ggplot(mtcarros, aes(mpg, cyl))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid_sc(gear~country, scales = list(x=scales_x))
```

[image]

You can set breaks, etc individually for each factor level of each faceting variable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I really need two variable on the right hand side of the faceting formula. The graph is built successfully but the problem is I can't create individual scales for the x-axis. That was the purpose of the question.

Comment: @AlitonOliveira yes - you will see that I have specified individual scales for the x axis in my answer. The package you are using does not allow two faceting variables on the right hand side. How do you want that to look? Do you want them nested? Did you understand my point about your formula implying a 3d array of facets?

Comment: Now I understand your point! The graph should be nested in columns with `carb` and `country`. Could you add an example with the package you mentioned (`ggh4x`)?

Comment: @AlitonOliveira with your data example, the resulting plot would be 12 panels by 3 panels since there is no clear nesting hierarchy and you need 3 x 3 x 4 panels. This is probably too many to have in a single plot. Unless you have only two or three factor levels in the three variables you might need to rethink how you are plotting here. Can I ask what you are trying to show?